# Please help me with this question relations and discrete maths.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've missed a massive chunk of lectures in my discrete math module. 
My exam is in 2 days and I really would appreciate help with this. Here is the question I'm having problems with:

Given the relation R such that $R = \{(m, n) ∈ R|m, n \in A, m^2 − n \ge 4\}$ when $A$
is the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$,

(i) express the relation $R$ as a set of ordered pairs.

I don't really understand the "$R = \{(m, n) ∈ R|m, n \in A, m^2 − n \ge 4\}$" part I kind of know that whatever pairs I'll get they will be less than $4$, but I don't know how to get those pairs. I'm really stuck and help would be much appreciated , please.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$m^2-n \geq 4$$ means

$$n \leq m^2-4\tag{1}$$

Now let $m=0$, and we get $n \leq 0^2-4=-4$, and we can see that we found no solution when $m=0$.

Try other values of $m$ and try to find all such solution.

Edit:

Your working for $m=1$ is correct.

Now, for $m=2$, $n \leq m^2-4=0$, we have $0 \leq 0$, we can let $n=0$, hence $(m,n)=(2,0)$ is in the relation.

Now try it for $m=3$ and $m=4$.

Comment: Okay, in the past exam papers the answers says to be R = {(2, 0),(3, 0),(3, 1),(3, 2),(4, 0),(4, 1),(4, 2),(4, 3)} but I still dont know how

Comment: try to substitute $m=1$ inside equation $(1)$? and see the inequality that you obtain? then try $m=2,3,4$.

Comment: I've done n ≤ 1(squared) − 4 and got n ≤ -3   also did the same with n ≤ 2(squared) − 4  and so on but I just don't see the solution arising maybe because I'm just dumb but can you please elaborate the process of getting the answer in a different way? (Sorry I couldn't find how to do the squared symbol)

Comment: See the edit. [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) reference to help you type maths. surround mathy object with dollar sign, for 'squared' use ^2.

Comment: Just list them one after another. If $m = 0$ then $n\le 0 - 4$.  That's impossible.  If $m = 1$ then $n \le 1 - 4$.  That's impossible.  If $m = 2$ then $n \le 4-4 = 0$ that's only possible if $n= 0$ so $(m,n) = (2,0)$ is possible.  If $m = 3$ then $n \le 9-4 = 5$ so $n$ can be 0,1,2,3,4 so $(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4)$ are possible.  If $m = 4$ then $n \le 16 - 4 = 12$ os $n$ can be $0,1,2,3,4$ so $(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)$

Comment: I'd have done it slightly differently. I'd have noted $m^2 \ge n + 4$ so for $n=0$, $m^2 \ge 4$ so $m=2,3,4$ so $(2,0),(3,0),(4,0)$.  For $n = 1$ $m^2 \ge 1+4 =5$ so $m = 3,4$ so $(3,1)(4,1)$.  For $n=2$ $m^2 \ge 2+4 = 6$ so $m=3,4$ so $(3,2)(4,2)$ etc.